# What were the salient features of Ekayana Vaishnavism (Kashmiri Vaishnavism)?

Tags: philosophy, vaishnavism, tradition

Kashmir was once a hub of Sanskrit and Indian philosophies or traditions like Shaivism, Vaishnavism, Buddhism etc. In ancient times, a tradition called Kashmiri Vaishnavism also flourished which was based on Tantra and Agamas which has gone extinct now because of Vaishnavas over the time gone into Vedanta and also due to Islamic fundamentalism. I want to know what were the salient features of Ekayana Vaishnavism (Kashmiri Vaishnavism)?

Comment: Can you provide any links where i can know more basic info about Ekayana Vaishnavism?

Comment: Is it totally extinct? Has it absolutely dissolved?

Comment: Ekayana refers to the Ekayana Shakha of the Shukla Yajur Veda.  The Pancharatra Agamas originated from the Ekayana Shakha.  The followers of the Ekayana Shakha were indeed centered in Kashmir, which is why the Pancharatra Agamas are also called Kashmira Agamas.  In any case, the Ekayana Shakha is now extinct, but there's no reason to believe that the followers of the Ekayana Shakha were any different from followers of Pancharatra today.  In particular, there's no reason to believe they weren't Vedantins.

Comment: Did they write voluminous commentaries on Brahma Sutras? How they were Vedantins?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury They were non dualists like KS.